# Plotting a model in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, model, ggplot2

I have used the *vglm()* function from the VGAM package to obtain a Weibull model for some data. I would like to plot the curve that this model is represented by. How do I do this?

Here's my input and output (I am comparing 'p_seen' to 'calculated_logmar', which exist in the dataframe 'dframe1'):

```
> my_model <- vglm(formula = p_seen ~ calculated_logmar, family = weibull, data = dframe1)

Pearson Residuals:
  log(shape) log(scale)
1    0.78928  -0.093136
2   -1.21092  -0.978527
3    0.12519   0.020018

Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error   z value
(Intercept):1      1.4797e+01 1.0803e+00  13.69619
(Intercept):2      4.5824e-06 2.3095e-05   0.19841
calculated_logmar -1.5324e+01 1.4448e+00 -10.60582

Number of linear predictors:  2 

Names of linear predictors: log(shape), log(scale)

Dispersion Parameter for weibull family:   1

Log-likelihood: 9.46132 on 3 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations: 30
```

I understand that the coefficients must relate somehow to the model itself, but I have no idea how to turn these coefficients into meaningful plots.

PS: I would like to use *ggplot2* to visualise my data if possible.

**Edit**: I have tried using the command:

```
plotvgam(my_model, se = TRUE, lcol = dframe1$calculated_logmar[1], scol = dframe1$calculated_logmar[1], which.term = 1)
```

This gives me a plot of 'calculated_logmar' against 'partial for calculated_logmar'. What I'm looking for is the actual curve of the model, showing calculated_logmar plotted against p_seen. *If* it is possible, I'd like to render this using *ggplot2*. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you will describe your variables, show real data or make a script to create a fictional data with given properties.

Comment: No problem - see the image here; this is the same thing (stress is what I'm calling calculated_logmar, and probability of failure is what I'm calling p_seen). Otherwise, it's all the same >> http://opticalengineering.spiedigitallibrary.org/data/Journals/OPTICE/22117/114001_1_6.png ... Essentially I want to model those data, and plot on the same axes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but you can plot the fitted values from the model against the predictor variable in the normal way:

```
## Generate example data
set.seed(123)
n <- 100
x <- runif(n)
d <- data.frame(
  x = x, 
  y = rweibull(n, shape=exp(1+x), scale=exp(-0.5)))

## Fit the model and create a new data set with the fitted values
library(VGAM)
m <- vglm(y ~ x, data=d, family=weibull)
p <- data.frame(
  x = d$x, 
  y.fit = fitted(m))

## Create the plot using ggplot (and mimicking the style in OP's comment link) 
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(p, aes(x, y.fit)) + geom_smooth() + geom_point(size=4, shape=1, alpha=0.6)
```

[image]

You might get a better response for this kind of question on SO, and my disclaimer is that I'm not familiar with this kind of model or the `VGAM` package, but hopefully this will at least point you in the right direction. A better CV answer would explain how all these things work...

Answer (score 3):

According to [package documentation](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v32/i10/paper) there is a function called `plotvgam` for plotting vglm results:

```
fit2.ms <- vglm(mstatus ~ poly(age, 2) + foo(age) + age,
+ family = multinomial(refLevel = 2), constraints = clist,
+ data = nzmarital)
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
plotvgam(fit2.ms, se = TRUE, scale = 12, lcol = mycol[1],
+ scol = mycol[1], which.term = 1)
plotvgam(fit2.ms, se = TRUE, scale = 12, lcol = mycol[2],
+ scol = mycol[2], which.term = 2)
plotvgam(fit2.ms, se = TRUE, scale = 12, lcol = mycol[3],
+ scol = mycol[3], which.term = 3)
```

Comment: Please see question edit above. Thanks for the tip, this has at least allowed me to plot *something*...